# Strapi deletes database after publish in server

Tags: angular, mongodb, strapi

I'm using strapi with angular and mongodb but I have a problem when I publish strapi in server after few hours the database is deleted, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is there a ransom message left behind?

Comment: no nothing !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a free plan of a hosting platform, it may be cleaning some files im order to save hosting platform space